# How are php files secured

Tags: php, security

I was wondering how php files are actually secured. How come one can not download a php file, even if the exact location is known?

When I upload a php file to my webserver, lets say to domain.com/files, and I call the domain.com/files page, I can clearly see the php file and its actual size. Downloading the file however leads to an empty file.

The question then is: How does the security mechanism work exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web server's responsibility is to take the PHP script and hand it to the PHP interpreter, which sends the HTML (or other) output back to the web server.

A mis-configured web server may fail to handle the PHP script properly, and send it down to the requesting browser in its raw form, and that would make it possible to access PHP scripts directly.

Your web hosting may have a mechanism to list the contents of a directory, but the unless it supplies a download mechanism to supply the PHP script with plain text headers (as opposed to HTML) without handing it to the PHP interpreter, it will be executed as PHP rather than served down.

In order to be able to download the raw PHP file, the server would have to do some extra work (possibly via another PHP script) which reads the PHP file from disk and sends its contents down to the browser with plain text headers.

Answer (score 2):

When you request domain.com/files your web server is setup to show all the files in that directory.

When you request the actual php file the web server executes it and outputs the results back to you - not the source code.

Of course, both of the above can be configured. You could switch of directory listing and disable parsing of php files so the actual file contents/source code is output.

Its usually a good practice to switch off directory listing.

Comment: Yes, I was going to turn off directory listing, but somehow it doesn't seem to work. My httpd.conf file looks as follow: http://pastebin.com/b6rgh15h What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you first install PHP on your server, it reconfigures Apache so that when a .php file is requested, Apache hands processing over to PHP. PHP then processes the code in the file, and returns whatever text the PHP code `echo`ed or `print`ed to Apache, which then sends that back over the network to the person that requested the PHP file.

The "security" comes simply in that Apache does not simply serve the PHP file, but rather hands it over to the PHP processor for execution. If Apache is not configured correctly or you use a server software that does not recognize PHP, the raw PHP file *will* be sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: since the server is configured to execute PHP files and return the results, you will never be able to access the PHP source from the outside. All code is executed immediately by the server. So, to answer your question:

The security mechanism is that .php files are executed automatically by the server when they are requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge misconception. When you attempt to access a PHP file over port 80, your request is likely being run through a web server **which does something with the file**. In the case of PHP, it runs that file through the PHP interpreter, which causes that file to create some output, and **that** is what is sent to you.

You can easily allow downloading of PHP files by removing the interpreter for that file type. If the web server doesn't have anything special for it and doesn't understand the file, it will just have the client download it.